# Merg data from multiple sheets with not defined number of rows

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to merge data of two Google spreadsheet sheets with a varying amount of rows.

I found this question:

[Merging data in google sheets from multiple sheets with varying number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961549/merging-data-in-google-sheets-from-multiple-sheets-with-varying-number-of-rows)
(I hope it is correct to open up a new question about it)

I predefined following named ranges:

```
Member:
Memberlist!B2:H6
MemberColumn:
Memberlist!B:B

Team:
Teamlist!B2:H6
TeamColumn:
Teamlist!B:B
```

And that is the Formula I am trying to use (based on the question)

```
={FILTER(Team;TeamColumn <> '');Filter(Member;MemberColumn <> '')}
```

What Have I got wrong? it is just showing me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you broke the universe of Google Sheets more than twice...

- for "nothing" you need pair of double quotes `""`
- ranges in `FILTER` needs to be of the same size so pick one that suits you:

  - `=FILTER(Memberlist!B2:H6; Memberlist!B2:B6<>"")`
  - `=FILTER(Memberlist!B:H; Memberlist!B:B<>"")`
- and ranges of constructed array need to be of the same size as well so:

  - `={FILTER(Memberlist!B2:H6; Memberlist!B2:B6<>""); 
       FILTER(Teamlist!B2:H6; Teamlist!B2:B6<>"")}`
  - `={FILTER(Memberlist!B:H; Memberlist!B:B<>""); 
       FILTER(Teamlist!B:H; Teamlist!B:B<>"")}`

Comment: I actually used double quotes (but I thought thats a thing of the german google sheets as well as the semicolon instead of the regular one)

The range thing solved it, thank you very much!